# Python ValueError To many values to unpack

Tags: python

Iam struggling to understand why the first way works and the second throws error.
Suppose we have this array

```
interests =[(0,"Hadoop"),(0,"Big Data"),(0,"HBase"),(0,"Java"),(0,"Spark"),(0,"Storm"),(0,"Cassandra"),(1,"NoSQL",0),
            (1,"MongoDB"),(1,"Cassandra"),(1,"HBase"),(1,"Postgres"),(2,"Python"),(2,"scikit-learn"),(2,"scipy"),(2,"numpy"),
            (2,"statsmodels"),(2,"pandas"),(3,"R"),(3,"Python"),(3,"statistics"),(3,"regression"),(3,"probability"),
            (4,"machine learning"),(4,"regression"),(4,"decision trees"),(4,"libsvm"),(5,"Python"),(5,"R"),(5,"Java"),
            (5,"C++"),(5,"Haskell"),(5,"programming languages"),(6,"statistics"),(6,"probability"),(6,"mathematics"),
            (6,"theory"),(7,"machine learning"),(7,"scikit-learn"),(7,"Mahoot"),(7,"neural networks"),(8,"neural networks"),
            (8,"deep learning"),(8,"Big Data"),(8,"artificial intelligence"),(9,"Hadoop"),(9,"Java"),(9,"MapReduce"),
            (9,"Big Data")]
```

1)I want to iterate over the tuple-elements of this list like this.

```
for x, y in interests:
    print(x,y)
```

This works only for tuples with first element equals  to 0 and then throws value error.
2)Below, this way works.

```
for interest in interests:
    print(interest[0],interest[1])
```

3)And lastly this way below also gives the same result with the first way.

```
for interest in interests:
    x,y = interest
    print(x,y)
```

I cant imagine how i can unpack correct the values

Comment: There's just a typo in your `interests` list. Use the following to print the list and you'll see what's wrong: `for x in interests: print(repr(x))`

Comment: The element "(1,"NoSQL",0)" is a 3-tuple. Is this an error? Or you have 2- and 3-tuples to handle?

Comment: Clearly, it is an error. Especially, this is an example from the Book " Data science from scratch" of Joel Grus. Nevermind, it is a typo error caused by me. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only printing the first couple tuples(Until 0,"Cassandra") because the one right after it has 3 elements inside it - (1,"NoSQL",0), the for loop has only mentioned x,y (2)

You can use this instead -

```py
interests =[(0,"Hadoop"),(0,"Big Data"),(0,"HBase"),(0,"Java"),(0,"Spark"),(0,"Storm"),(0,"Cassandra"),(1,"NoSQL",0),
            (1,"MongoDB"),(1,"Cassandra"),(1,"HBase"),(1,"Postgres"),(2,"Python"),(2,"scikit-learn"),(2,"scipy"),(2,"numpy"),
            (2,"statsmodels"),(2,"pandas"),(3,"R"),(3,"Python"),(3,"statistics"),(3,"regression"),(3,"probability"),
            (4,"machine learning"),(4,"regression"),(4,"decision trees"),(4,"libsvm"),(5,"Python"),(5,"R"),(5,"Java"),
            (5,"C++"),(5,"Haskell"),(5,"programming languages"),(6,"statistics"),(6,"probability"),(6,"mathematics"),
            (6,"theory"),(7,"machine learning"),(7,"scikit-learn"),(7,"Mahoot"),(7,"neural networks"),(8,"neural networks"),
            (8,"deep learning"),(8,"Big Data"),(8,"artificial intelligence"),(9,"Hadoop"),(9,"Java"),(9,"MapReduce"),
            (9,"Big Data")]
for x,y,*a in interests:
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in your data:

interests =[(0,"Hadoop"),(0,"Big Data"),(0,"HBase"),(0,"Java"),(0,"Spark"),(0,"Storm"),(0,"Cassandra"),***(1,"NoSQL",0)***,
(1,"MongoDB"),(1,"Cassandra"),(1,"HBase"),(1,"Postgres"),(2,"Python"),(2,"scikit-learn"),(2,"scipy"),(2,"numpy"),
(2,"statsmodels"),(2,"pandas"),(3,"R"),(3,"Python"),(3,"statistics"),(3,"regression"),(3,"probability"),
(4,"machine learning"),(4,"regression"),(4,"decision trees"),(4,"libsvm"),(5,"Python"),(5,"R"),(5,"Java"),
(5,"C++"),(5,"Haskell"),(5,"programming languages"),(6,"statistics"),(6,"probability"),(6,"mathematics"),
(6,"theory"),(7,"machine learning"),(7,"scikit-learn"),(7,"Mahoot"),(7,"neural networks"),(8,"neural networks"),
(8,"deep learning"),(8,"Big Data"),(8,"artificial intelligence"),(9,"Hadoop"),(9,"Java"),(9,"MapReduce"),
(9,"Big Data")]

You have a third element in the bolded text which python is complaining about.